# Django как вывести загруженные изображения

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте, прошу помочь с возникшем затруднением.

Пробую делать блог на **Django/Python**, хочу вывести статьи с картинками. Картинка по **url** из админики грузится, а из шаблона нет, подскажите пожалуйста куда копать. Гуглил, Яндексил, ничего не нашел рабочего.

**models.py:**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return unicode(self.title)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root':'media'}),

]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py:**

```
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**article.html:**

```
{% for article in articles %}
        <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
        <img src="{article.image}">
        <p>{{ article.text}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

(Пробовал `article.image.url` вылетает ошибка)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум:

```
<img src="{{ article.image.url }}">
```

А не

```
<img src="{article.image}">
```

При использовании `{{ article.image.url }}` какую ошибку наблюдаете?

Comment: Exception Value:  

The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: Решил проблему удалением всех постов. Добавил новый пост с изображением, и он отобразился корректно. Возникает следующий вопрос: как избежать возникновения ошибки, если пост будет без картинки? Заранее благодарю за ответ

Comment: Подсказка - надо проверять, есть ли картинка или нет